# implement image zoom using prototype

Tags: prototypejs

I trying to zoom an image using Prototype.

till now i have tried using prototypes zoomer, but dint succeeded.

is any one have able to zoom image using prototype than please let me know the method.

Comment: Are you referring to something similar to lightbox? I use FancyZoom Box to do that. https://github.com/jnunemaker/fancy-zoom

Comment: yes, you got my point.. is it possible to make this fancy zoom on mouse hover event

Comment: In that git repo Line 218 of the prototypejs implementation has `observe('click'...` you can change to whatever you need it to be https://github.com/jnunemaker/fancy-zoom/blob/master/prototype/js/fancyzoom.js#L218